# Name of iOS list element that rakes with scroll

Tags: iphone, list, ios, nomenclature

In iOS, what do you call that element that attaches to the top of the screen when you scroll past it in a list (think the single letters in the Contact List). This is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not sure this is even a full question, but the answer is 'section'. If you're table style is plain, the section title will behave like the A-Z in the iPhone contacts screen
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry for the vagueness of the question, but I really have no idea how to even ask what this thing is.

Comment: I hope i could at least help a bit :)

Answer (score 0):

It is the section header of a [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:).
Its appearance depends on the tableview style.
Like in the contacts app, like header stay at the top of the section unless the top of the section is off the screen and there are rows in the section which are still visible.

Like in the settings app the header just appears as text on the striped background and scrolls with the table view no matter what. It doesn't ever get attached to the top.